# Need to develop a tapered spacer for under a car lift on an angled concrete slab

Tags: concrete, epoxy, fiberglass

I need to fabricate/develop an angled spacer.  13 inch wide by 10 inch long, by 3/4 inch to 1 3/8 inch thick. This spacer is needed to go under two of the posts of a hobbyist car lift in my garage.

The garage floor is angled by the door where two of the four corner posts will go. These two rear posts need to be on a flat surface and at the same level as the two front posts.  Each post pad will need to handle approximately 2000 pounds.

I was thinking of building a 4-sided mold where the column pads would be on the angled concrete and pouring some type of epoxy, resin, or cement into the mold. Which the metal plate from car lift posts would sit on.
enter image description here

[image]

Comment: In my humble opinion I think you should go to a metal fab shop and have them construct the spacers. Concrete will crumble since there's no room to reinforce it and epoxy will probably crack upon impact.

Comment: In my experience such lifts require proper footings under the slab. Point loads of that magnitude are likely to crack it and cause settling. Are you sure you won't be cutting holes in it anyway?

Comment: Please show us the base of this lift. Shims needn't be full-size for such an application, and the means of anchoring it are important.

Comment: I am glad to see that it is a 4 post lift, so stability won't be too much of an issue, nor will the bolts and their holding strength, at least not as much as a 2 post lift.

Comment: My initial thought was to use two metal plates and angled side plates for each of the two posts spacers.  Unfortunately, where the spacers need to go, the floor is not level from one side to the other. So, I would need to custom build it on location and then have a welder weld it, to fit correctly. Not impossible, but not convenient, nor cost effective. Was looking for answer that I could do myself.

Comment: You have a car lift and a nice car. Minimising cost isn't really top priority.

Comment: You're thinking too small.  I think you need a quality concrete pad for the whole lift area, engineered and reinforced with internal rebar/mesh/rod.  It shoud be tied into the existing floor too, not just poured on top.  Think worst-case of an earthquake while there's a car on the lift, and the forces involved.    You should also find out if lifts need certification in your location.

Answer (score 3):

Isherwood has good points about the capacity of the floor slab, you need to confirm what you have. A standard 4" slab may not hold up to the rigors of the lift. If the install guide says differently or you know you have a  thicker slab that can take it, then carry on...

Non shrink grout is typically used for this type of condition. Pack it fully by pushing it through to the other side of the form so you can see it bulging up against the form you have set about 1" maybe more away from the metal base. Keep adding until the area is packed. It seems you may be able to use the butt end of a 1X4 to pack it in, leaving one side of the form off to pack by. The last side will not need the form. Just mound it up to keep it from "slumping back" from the underside of the metal base. The forms you make would need to be the height of the gap under the base, it can be higher, so using 2X4s or 2X2s are a good idea.

Once the grout has gotten its initial set, were you can slice off a section of the mound and it does not lose its shape, remove the forms and slope the  grout to a 45 degree angle from the metal base to the floor.

Comment: I agree that non-shrink grout is the norm for installing steel posts which is basically what is being discussed here. Regarding the capacity of the slab, if it is slab on grade (fully supported on soil) then the first consideration is the soil. Typical rule of thumb for foundations is 1500 psf. I doubt that the slab will be an issue; the worst that would occur is some cracking.

Comment: Size and the depth of the anchor bolts will be an issue. If the wedge anchors or sleeve anchors go through the slab or even into the blown out portion when the drill pops through, the bolts will not be at their optimum hold.

Comment: +1 for suggesting non-shrink grout. I wouldn’t use anything else.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback and suggestion.  I know nothing about non-shrink grout. I started to do research and found Five-Star.  -  https://www.fivestarproducts.com/products/cement-grouts/grout.html

Comment: If that is a product that is locally available, that is what is needed. Any non shrink grout will do that I am aware of, all have a very high compression strength. It can, as all NS grout, can be mixed to any consistency that suits your purpose. I mix mine typically a little past dry pack which dry pack is just wet enough that the mix crumbles while mixing, but when a hand full is squeezed, it stays together. The "push stick" method in my answer will work with dry pack very well if you choose to go that route. You must realy shove it in hard to pack it tight. That form will help.

Answer (score 0):

Use wood to create a shim.

2000 lbs on 130 square inches (13x10 per your post) is about 15 psi (pounds per square inch) while the strength of wood used this manner is around 400 psi. Wood is cheap, easy to source and easy to cut as well.

Comment: Wood will, however, compress over time and that could leave the lift tilted. I wouldn't want a 4000lb car over my head on a potentially tilted lift.

Comment: It would also need to be treated against decay.

Comment: @FreeMan that's simple not true at all. In your response, provide a source that supports your comment (you won't find one). Re isherwood, it would not need to be pressure treated in this case. Yes it's in contact with concrete however it is not true that all wood in contact with concrete shall be PT (though that is what many people believe). PT wood is acceptable, and the reduction in capacity is only 10% so still plenty strong for this application

Comment: It shall be if it's going in *my* garage. I wasn't referring to building codes.

Comment: @isherwood Actually the Code does require ALL wood in contact with a concrete slab and shall be an approved species of wood AND shall be treated in accordance with AWPA pressure treatment. (See ICC R319.1.3) unless slab is on impervious moisture barrier. Some wood species do not require treatment: heartwood of Redwood, cedar and black locus. (Just try finding those species.)

Comment: @FreeMan You are correct that wood is not acceptable for a base. As soon as my lift starts, there’s a jarring movement and would crack (split) the wood “filler”. Besides, the lift manufacturer recommends it be bolted down to concrete... not wood. I agree with Jack. I used non-shrink grout on thickened slab.